# SQL Server Invalid Column name after adding new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I just added an identity column to an existing table with data through the `SSMS` Designer, the table updates fine and I can run a select query against it successfully, but after the query finishes I noticed that the new column is underlined in red with an error indicating it's an invalid column name.

Why does this occur?  I would expect the query to fail if the column was invalid.

Does the SSMS keep some type of internal reference to the old table that must be flushed?

I tried closing the DB connection and reopening it, but still the same error.  Not sure what I'm missing here.

```
SELECT TOP 100 
[PRIMARY_NDX_Col1],
[NEW_Col], --QUERY EXECUTES SUCCESSFULLY, BUT THIS IS UNDERLINED RED AS AN INVALID COLUMN
[Col3]
FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
```

Comment: Just tried restarting and that fixed it.  Wonder if there's a way to dynamically clear the SSMS 2008 cache after editing a table.  This seems like the kind of bug people could spend hours trying to troubleshoot.

Comment: You don't need to restart SSMS to fix this. Keep this article handy, one of the most common causes is that SSMS just isn't fast enough in refreshing its local cache of metadata. http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2591/troubleshooting-intellisense-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012/

Comment: Please explain why the answers provided are not acceptable for this question so that enhancements to them may be provided. @AaronBertrand good tips in there!

Answer (score 232):

you can either

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

OR

- Go to Edit >> IntelliSense >> Refresh Local
  Cache

Comment: I'm sorry i'm asking this here after one year.. I am using sql server 2000 ad I don't have a control CTRL+SHIFT+R or something called IntelliSense and i'm getting the same problem.. Any idea ?

Comment: Just some more info: "If a view currently used is modified by using ALTER VIEW, the Database Engine takes an exclusive schema lock on the view. When the lock is granted, and there are no active users of the view, the Database Engine deletes all copies of the view from the procedure cache. Existing plans referencing the view remain in the cache but are recompiled when invoked."
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173846.aspx (see the remarks section)

Comment: I have one problem in this,I had altered some column name from design and saved the table. I did refresh to intellisense local cache...Now in the query, the changes works and redline for errors reacts but when I run that query, it again shows error message "invalid column name" and when I write back old name then it works..... Help me in this......!!!!

Comment: If it seems like it doesn't work, count to ten. It takes a little while to refresh and there's no sign when it's working or completed.

Comment: CTRL-SHIFT-R didn't to the trick for me. Had to explicitly click Refresh Local Cache in SSMS 15.0.18131.0. Thanks!

Comment: If it doesn't work even after following @David's answer, try closing and reopening SSMS. This worked for me.