# All column names in my view are underlined in red in SSMS

Tags: sql-server-2008

I created the view View_DefectDaysOutstanding3. when I select to see the data, it gives the data, but why in the select statement all the fields are underlined in red as error?

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [ID]
          ,[Severity]
          ,[AvgDaysOutstanding]
          ,[ReportMonth]
          ,[ReportYearMonth]
          ,[#OfBugs]
          ,[projid]
          ,[folderid]
      FROM [SoftwarePlanner].[dbo].[View_DefectDaysOutstanding3]
      order by ReportYearMonth
```

Comment: Duplicate of [SQL Server Invalid Column name after adding new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338609/sql-server-invalid-column-name-after-adding-new-column)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

[Have you refreshed your Intellisense cache?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dtjones/archive/2008/09/11/refreshing-the-intellisense-cache.aspx)

Keyboard shortcut:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

Or, using the menu: `Edit` -> `IntelliSense` -> `Refresh Local Cache`

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Could you please tell me, why my view data gives different result than the data I get directly using the sql query wich is used to create the view?

Comment: or via command palette: (ctrl or cmd)+shift+p "refre..."

Answer (score 5):

Go to Edit > IntelliSense > select "Refresh Local Cache".

You need to refresh your cache after you create new tables/add columns/ new views etc

Comment: Hi I don't see this shortcut, Edit > Intellisense > refresh local cache

Comment: Could you please tell me, why my view data gives different result than the data I get directly using the sql query wich is used to create the view?

Comment: @user2145798 Your cursor/focus has to be in the query editor window for the Edit menu to show the IntelliSense option.