# Invalid Column Name - All Columns in Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

All of my references to a column existing in table `departments` are getting binding errors. (they are highlighted) However, all of my saved queries referencing this table, though the column references are highlighted, still execute properly. NEW queries do not.

```
select 
    i.itemnum, i.itemname 
from 
    inventory i 
join 
    departments d on i.dept_id = d.DEPT_ID 
join 
    categories c on d.SUBTYPE = c.cat_id 

where c.description = 'vapors'
```

In the above query,  both `d.DEPT_ID` and `d.SUBTYPE` are highlighted as `invalid column name`, though they are both most definitely fields that are available in `departments` and will still return results.

Even in the following query I still get a highlight on `DEPT_ID` in the code body

```
select DEPT_ID from departments
```

Queries that reference `departments` still execute, although they still show the red highlight on all references to `departments` in the code body

I'm wondering if I might have inadvertently changed a setting on `departments`, although I truly don't know how I would have done so...

Comment: Qualify all your column names and the problem will go away.  That is, precede the column name with `<alias>.`.

Comment: so second to last line, I forgot to add a qualifier on `dept_id` there @GordonLinoff, the query will now execute, but I'm still not understanding why those columns are flagged as `invalid`... It's literally any query that i write referencing any table from `departments` and no other table does this. This has only happened the past two days

Comment: You need to use the alias On the columns in the where clause too

Comment: It is hard to give exact error fix without schema so put them it will be helpful to all.

Comment: Are you using SSMS?

Comment: Please add the table definitions to your question, and post the full error message you are getting from (I assume) SSMS. If you are not getting an error message, can you add a screen shot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All column names in my view are underlined in red in SSMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281193/all-column-names-in-my-view-are-underlined-in-red-in-ssms)

Comment: If you are using SSMS then the highlights are there because you need to clear the Intellisense cache. The errors are phantom.

Comment: @nicomp yes I am

Comment: @nicomp, I'll give that a shot

Comment: @nicomp smh, problem solved

Comment: "CTRL + SHIFT + R"  is the Intellisense cache clear command in SSMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear your Intellisense cache. The errors/highlights are phantom. If your code works, ignore the errors or clear the cache.

"CTRL + SHIFT + R"

Answer (score 0):

If your query is running properly and giving the expected results and only your are worry about column not highlighting then you can close and re open the SSMS and check.

If you create any new tables and do not close the SSMS then some time that new tables and columns do not give refreshed.