# Why is my table not fully recognized by the Query pane in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I created a new table (MOVIES_SINGLETABLE) as part of my Flix4Fams database. The table appears in the list of tables, but in the query pane it is not recognized (as seen by the squiggly lines under its name):

[image]

Also, it does come up in the list of table names:

[image]

Yet, when I run the query against it, I get no err msg that the table does not exist. It should have records, but it says there are none. Why is it being treated like a "red-headed stepchild"?

It's accepted, in a sense, but not completely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [All column names in my view are underlined in red in SSMS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15281193/2029983)

Comment: Ah, interesting - I refreshed the database itself until the cows came home, but didn't think of refreshing Intellisense - thanks.

Comment: Yeah it's annoying - you'd think that refreshing the objects in the explorer would update Intellisense too, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be the issue - sometimes Intellisense (the engine that does the underlining etc)
takes a bit of time to update.

You can force a refresh with ctrl-shift-r or this button

[image]

If the button is not there, I add it to a toolbar

- On the right side of the toolbar, click the down arrow and select 'add or remove buttons'
- Select 'Customise'
- Click 'Add command...'
- Choose the 'Edit' category
- Scroll to 'Refresh local cache' and select it
- Move the button to your preferred location on the toolbar
- 'Modify selection' if you want to (say) include text next to the button

Comment: Strange; I had refreshed before (both the DB and the table), with no effect. I added the "Refresh" button and it was indeed a squiggle-be-gone, apparently. Thanks.

Comment: Completely understand. I only know about this because the squiggle annoys me too.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon, Ctrl-Shift-R is a refresh of the Intellisense cache, not a refresh of DB or table.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov: I know that Ctrl-Shift-R does not refresh the database; I did that by right-clicking on the DB and the table and refreshing them.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon, I meant to say that right-clicking on the DB and the table and refreshing them in the Object Explorer refreshes only the view in the left pane of the SSMS (in the Object Explorer) pane. My point is that it is not strange that when you refreshed the DB and the table, the Intellisense cache was not refreshed. It is just how SSMS works. Refresh of the view in the Object Explorer does not update the cache of Intellisense. To refresh the Intellisense cache and to get rid of the squiggly lines you need to use a different command (Ctrl-Shift-R).