# Invalid column name when running a query in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to run a query in SQL Server 2008. It looks like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE name = "Bonds" AND type = 'U')
    DROP table Bonds
GO
```

When I run this, I get this error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>    Invalid column name 'Bonds'.
>    Msg 28102, Level 16, State 1, Line 3

This query was created by SQL Server. I am trying to run it in a different computer. Then I face this issue.

I have tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> as this post: [SQL Server Invalid Column name after adding new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338609/sql-server-invalid-column-name-after-adding-new-column). But it is not helping.

Need some guidance on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
WHERE name = "Bonds"
```

to

```
WHERE name = 'Bonds'
```

Otherwise `"Bonds"` is treated like a column-name which does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

use `single quotes` in search condition

```
WHERE name = 'Bonds'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also use

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;
```

before your query.