# Not able to find mistake in query giving Invalid column error

Tags: sql-server

I'm writing this query but getting error 'Invalid Column' I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338609/sql-server-invalid-column-name-after-adding-new-column)
but no luck,
below is table and error

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can't self reference an Aliased column within the same query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the alias in the same `SELECT` statement. Either you put it in a subquery:

```
SELECT
    npv, npv - 1000
FROM (
    SELECT (listprice - standardcost) * quantity AS npv
    FROM SampleTable
) t
```

Or reuse the formula:

```
SELECT 
    (listprice - standardcost) * quantity AS npv,
    ((listprice - standardcost) * quantity) - 1000
FROM SampleTable
```

If you're using the formula multiple times in nested or joined queries, you can put it in a `CTE`:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *
        (listprice - standardcost) * quantity AS npv,
        ((listprice - standardcost) * quantity) - 1000 AS colAlias -- your alias here
    FROM SampleTale
)
SELECT * FROM Cte
```

The next time you use that formula, `SELECT` from the `CTE` instead.

Comment: If my formula is too long and need to use multiple time in query then is this the only way to do or any short way??